# Awk condition on a file while keeping the first line

Tags: awk

I have this kind of file :

```
IdxFirst  IdxCombined  IdxFirstNamed   IdxCombinedNamed  Counts  MeanScore
0         0            Univ_V3_bc1001  Univ_V3_bc1001    204158  95
1         1            Univ_V3_bc1002  Univ_V3_bc1002    187408  95
8         8            Univ_V3_bc1009  Univ_V3_bc1009    171808  95
8         9            Univ_V3_bc1009  Univ_V3_bc1010    380     98
8         11           Univ_V3_bc1009  Univ_V3_bc1012    350     97
9         9            Univ_V3_bc1010  Univ_V3_bc1010    253654  96
9         11           Univ_V3_bc1010  Univ_V3_bc1012    481     97
10        10           Univ_V3_bc1011  Univ_V3_bc1011    189661  96
11        11           Univ_V3_bc1012  Univ_V3_bc1012    238540  96
12        12           Univ_V3_bc1013  Univ_V3_bc1013    163897  96
12        13           Univ_V3_bc1013  Univ_V3_bc1014    317     98
12        15           Univ_V3_bc1013  Univ_V3_bc1016    404     96
13        13           Univ_V3_bc1014  Univ_V3_bc1014    150268  96
```

I want to get in output the first line , and the condition `awk '{if ($3==$4) print $0}'` . I tried `awk 'NR==1{print $0}' && '{if ($3==$4) print $0}' my_file` but it doesn't work. It should look like that :

```
IdxFirst  IdxCombined  IdxFirstNamed   IdxCombinedNamed  Counts  MeanScore
0         0            Univ_V3_bc1001  Univ_V3_bc1001    204158  95
1         1            Univ_V3_bc1002  Univ_V3_bc1002    187408  95
8         8            Univ_V3_bc1009  Univ_V3_bc1009    171808  95
9         9            Univ_V3_bc1010  Univ_V3_bc1010    253654  96
10        10           Univ_V3_bc1011  Univ_V3_bc1011    189661  96
11        11           Univ_V3_bc1012  Univ_V3_bc1012    238540  96
12        12           Univ_V3_bc1013  Univ_V3_bc1013    163897  96
13        13           Univ_V3_bc1014  Univ_V3_bc1014    150268  96
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} ($3==$4)' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply, don't run the condition check of comparing 3rd and 4th fields when its very first line(simply print first line) and rest of the lines we perform comparisons and it prints accordingly. How printing works for condition check `$3==$4` is `awk` works on method of condition and action, so if a condition is TRUE then an action mentioned after it will be performed, since here NO action is given so by default print of current line will happen.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || $3==$4' file
IdxFirst  IdxCombined  IdxFirstNamed   IdxCombinedNamed  Counts  MeanScore
0         0            Univ_V3_bc1001  Univ_V3_bc1001    204158  95
1         1            Univ_V3_bc1002  Univ_V3_bc1002    187408  95
8         8            Univ_V3_bc1009  Univ_V3_bc1009    171808  95
9         9            Univ_V3_bc1010  Univ_V3_bc1010    253654  96
10        10           Univ_V3_bc1011  Univ_V3_bc1011    189661  96
11        11           Univ_V3_bc1012  Univ_V3_bc1012    238540  96
12        12           Univ_V3_bc1013  Univ_V3_bc1013    163897  96
13        13           Univ_V3_bc1014  Univ_V3_bc1014    150268  96
```